# POST params on iOS webview not making it to the server

Tags: ios, post, webkit

I'm making a simple POST request with some body-params, constructed like so:

```
_webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds configuration:[WKWebViewConfiguration new]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:<some_URI>]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *paramsStr = @"someKey=someValue"
[request setHTTPBody:[paramsStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

My server endpoint never receives any POST params (the http-body seems to be empty)

I've seen discussions about `WKWebView` not providing `POST` data in the navigation delegate, but the use-case for those questions has been to fetch form data off of the webView. Further, I read that that WKWebView bug has been [fixed](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=179077).

My use case is very simple, I just want to make a POST request from a webview, but it's still not working. I'm on iOS 14.4 FWIW. Any tips on what could be causing the POST data to not be available on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript to solve the problem that WKWebView cannot send POST parameters

Before I start, let me talk about the implementation ideas, so that everyone can understand it. If something goes wrong, you can know the wrong place:

Put the HTML code of a POST request containing JavaScript in the project directory
Load the code of this POST request containing JavaScript to WKWebView

After loading, use Native to call JavaScript's POST method and pass in parameters to complete the request

HTML code to create a POST request containing JavaScript

Related code:

```objectivec
 <html>

<head>

    <script>

        //调用格式： post('URL', {"key": "value"});

        function post(path, params) {

            var method = "post";

            var form = document.createElement("form");

            form.setAttribute("method", method);

            form.setAttribute("action", path);

 

            for(var key in params) {

                if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");

                    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

                    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);

                    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

 

                    form.appendChild(hiddenField);

                }

            }

            document.body.appendChild(form);

            form.submit();

        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Copy this code and paste it into a text editor. You can choose any name, for example, save it as: JSPOST.html, and then copy it to the project directory. Remember to select the corresponding Target and check Copy items if needed (default It should be checked). At this time, you can use this JavaScript code to send a POST request with parameters.

Load the corresponding JavaScript code into WKWebView by loading a local web page

```objectivec
OC Code：

// JS sends the POST Flag, when it is true, it will call the JS POST method (only when the local JS is loaded for the first time)

self.needLoadJSPOST = YES;

// Create WKWebView

self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

//Set up proxy

self.webView.navigationDelegate = self;

// Get the path where JS is located

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"JSPOST" ofType:@"html"];

// Get html content

NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// load js

[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];

// Add WKWebView to the current View

[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
```

This code is equivalent to loading the JavaScript scripts in the project into WKWebView, and we will see how to use it later. (Please change to your file name)

Native calls JavaScript scripts and passes in parameters to complete the POST request

Remember the section on the interaction between WKWebView and JavaScript? Now Native calls JavaScript. If you forget, please go ahead and review the story:-webView:didFinishNavigation: The proxy indicates that the page has been loaded. Let's do it here. The following code:

```objectivec
OC Code：

// Proxy method after loading

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {

    // Determine whether to load (only for the first time)

    if (self.needLoadJSPOST) {

        // Call the method of sending POST request using JS

        [self postRequestWithJS];

        // Set Flag to NO (you don’t need to load it later)

        self.needLoadJSPOST = NO;

    }

}

 

// Call JS to send POST request

- (void)postRequestWithJS {

    // Send POST parameters

    NSString *postData = @"\"username\":\"aaa\",\"password\":\"123\"";

    // URL of the requested page

    NSString *urlStr = @"http://www.postexample.com";

    // Assembled into a string that calls JavaScript

    NSString *jscript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"post('%@', {%@});", urlStr, postData];

 

    // NSLog(@"Javascript: %@", jscript);

    // Call JS code

    [self.webView evaluateJavaScript:jscript completionHandler:^(id object, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    

    }];

}
```

you can see more here: http://www.qw021.com/article-22.html

Comment: I did the same, still no data is passed, Can u help !! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72870020/how-to-launch-lti-requests-with-form-data-from-ios